# Bootstrapping in R

Tags: r, bootstrap, algorithms

Is there anyway to perform a BCa, a tilted, and an ABC bootstrap in R without using the built in packages, namely 'boot'? Thanks

Comment: Well, you could write you own code ... What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I'm struggling even to find a basic example illustrating these different bootstraps. What I'm basically asking is, is there a simple formula that can be used, like the student-t bootstrap, to calculate each different type?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want to know the details of how to implement these functions yourself. If so, you can simply look at the source code of the `boot` package, which is available from [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot). For example, the BCa is calculated with the function:

```
bca.ci <-
    function(boot.out,conf = 0.95,index = 1,t0 = NULL,t = NULL, L = NULL,
             h = function(t) t, hdot = function(t) 1, hinv = function(t) t,
             ...)
#
#  Adjusted Percentile (BCa) Confidence interval method.  This method
#  uses quantities calculated from the empirical influence values to
#  improve on the precentile interval.  Usually the required order
#  statistics for this method will not be integers and so norm.inter
#  is used to find them.
#
{
    t.o <- t
    if (is.null(t) || is.null(t0)) {
        t <- boot.out$t[,index]
            t0 <- boot.out$t0[index]
    }
    t <- t[is.finite(t)]
    w <- qnorm(sum(t < t0)/length(t))
    if (!is.finite(w)) stop("estimated adjustment 'w' is infinite")
    alpha <- (1+c(-conf,conf))/2
    zalpha <- qnorm(alpha)
    if (is.null(L))
        L <- empinf(boot.out, index=index, t=t.o, ...)
    a <- sum(L^3)/(6*sum(L^2)^1.5)
    if (!is.finite(a)) stop("estimated adjustment 'a' is NA")
    adj.alpha <- pnorm(w + (w+zalpha)/(1-a*(w+zalpha)))
    qq <- norm.inter(t,adj.alpha)
    cbind(conf, matrix(qq[,1L],ncol=2L), matrix(hinv(h(qq[,2L])),ncol=2L))
}
```

Of course, it would be useful reading the papers that describe these methods.

Comment: I think this reply could be greatly enhanced by giving details on the why and how of the `empinf` and `norm.inter` functions.